# Automatic Gearbox switch with engine off

Tags: automatic-transmission, bmw, 320d

I have an automatic bmw e90 2005 - 320d.
I've been driving it for quite a while now, and few days ago i noticed something which I could not find info, and not certain if is okay.

With the car in P mode, and engine off. By mystake I tried to switch it to the reverse so and then to start the car. But then the transmission light came on and wouldn't allow me to switch from P to R mode.

Switched off the car and then turned it on - everything seems to be working okay now.

Just wondering if that is normal behavior, to protect the gear from switching with engine off?

ps:i could do it when i just turned off the car from N to P for example to get the key off the fob, but when the car has been off for a while and try to change it from P to R, the light came off.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure I understand the situation. Your car wasn't running, but the ignition was on when this happened? Then, the car allowed you to switch to R and you tried to start it, but instead of starting the transmission light came on ... then you couldn't place it back into P until you'd turned the ignition off? Am I reading it right? If so, this is most likely normal behavior and would be a safety feature, basically equating to a "Neutral Safety Switch" ... but since I really don't know much about BMW's, this is just a guess.

Comment: I have a different automatic (VW type) and it's impossible to move it out of Park without starting the engine. But as you say, it can be moved into Park after switching the engine off, to release the key.

Comment: Basically if the car is off and I try to move it from P to other positions, it displays the light.
If, however, the engine is on and I place is in N, turn off the engine, and then I can switch it to P. So I was just wondering if is normal to turn on the light, in that situation.